# What is $cov(Y_1,Y_2)$ if $Y_1 = \prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i$,$Y_2 = \prod_{i=2}^{n+1}X_i$ , and $X_{1..n+1}$ are $n+1$ bernoulli-distributed random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

$X_1,X_2,...,X_{n+1}$ are $n+1$ random variables that follow a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$.

We define $Y_1 = \prod_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ and $Y_2 = \prod_{i=2}^{n+1}X_i$.

How can I find out the covariance $cov(Y_1,Y_2)$ ?

---

I know that $$Cov(A,B) = E(A\cdot B) - E(A) \cdot E(B)$$

Here $E(Y_1) = E(Y_2) = p^n$ (I think?). But how do I find out $E(Y_1\cdot Y_2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that $X_i^2=X_i$ for every $i$ so that $Y_1Y_2=\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}X_{i}$.

To be found is $$\mathbb EY_1Y_2-\mathbb EY_1\mathbb EY_2=\mathbb{E}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}X_{i}-\left(\mathbb{E}\prod_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right)\left(\mathbb{E}\prod_{i=2}^{n+1}X_{i}\right)$$

If the rv's are independent then we find:$$=\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}\mathbb{E}X_{i}-\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}X_{i}\right)\left(\prod_{i=2}^{n+1}\mathbb{E}X_{i}\right)=p^{n+1}-p^{n}p^{n}=p^{n+1}-p^{2n}$$